# JavaScript Quadratic Formula Equation producing NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quadratic formula calculator. There are no errors but when I run it it returns NaN. I do not understand why.

```js
function quadratic(a, b, c) {    
  a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  c = document.getElementById("c").value;

  var equation = Math.sqrt((b * b) - ( 4 * a * c));
  var quadraticPos =(-b + equation) / (2 * a); 
  var quadraticNeg = (-b - equation) / (2 * a);

  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)) {
    alert("Invalid Input");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("quadraticOut").innerHTML =
      "Quadratic Equation = " + quadraticPos.toFixed(2) +
      "<br/>" + quadraticNeg.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```css
input { width: 20px }
```

```html
<input id="a" placeholder="a"/>
<input id="b" placeholder="b"/>
<input id="c" placeholder="c"/>
<button onclick="quadratic()">compute</button>
<div id="quadraticOut">result…</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: What are the values of a, b and c when you get NaN?

Comment: Im using a HTML file to get users input so It could be 5, 2, 7 or any three numbers.

Comment: Nope, that wont work. Try using a=5,b=6,c=1, otherwise you run the risk of taking the sqrt of a negative number and thus NaN. You can't have just any values in a quadratic equation.

Comment: We need to see that file. For all we know a, b, or c either don't exist or aren't elements you can read from such as `<input>`.

Comment: Why do you take `a`, `b`, and `c` as arguments to the function if you're just going to ignore their values in favor of what's in the inputs?

Comment: @ski I turned your code into a snippet. AFAICT your code still return NaN with a=5, b=2 and c=7

Comment: `var a=5, b=2, c=7; Math.sqrt((b * b) - ( 4 * a * c))` — NaN

Comment: I didn't know this, but "If the value of x is negative, Math.sqrt() returns NaN." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt). This is the main problem here. Updated answer below.

Comment: Even if using Math.pow(b, 2)

Comment: If the roots are nonreal it will return NaN

Answer (score 0):

1. The input check should come before the actual calculation.
2. `a`, `b` and `c` are by default strings, not numbers, when they come
   from the input fields through `.value`. They should be converted to `Number()` before being used in calculation. Or, you could multiply by a number, but that's a hack. If `b*b` multiplies two strings, the product will be a number because of type coercion, but this isn't solid and you should not rely on JavaScript oddities like this to make your calculation work.
3. `Math.sqrt()` returns NaN if the result is a negative number, which is very likely to get with random input values here.
4. Your `<br/>`in the innerHTML will cause an error, you need to put quotes around it.
5. In 2021 it would be better to use `let` and/or `const` in order to limit the variable scope, instead of the global `var`.